# Developer name already exists for given entity or has been previously used. Please choose a different name

Tags: apex, managed-package, ide, deprecation

In my managed ISV package I have many deprecated classes. Some of the are global and I cannot change their signature and just mark them as @deprecated.

To make it more obvious that a class is deprecated now I also tried to remove most of the code. When I hit save in my IDE I got the error:

> Developer name already exists for given entity or has been previously
>   used. Please choose a different name.

What does that mean?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this exact problem. Once a class has been marked deprecated and included in a Managed Package, you can no longer make **any** changes to it. Not even changes to the internals of a method.

I logged a case (#08766706) with Salesforce about this. The response I got was:

> It appears in its current form it is a limitation of the compiler, and it cannot be changed in the current version.
>
> That being said, the R&D team is working on an internal compiler upgrade that will probably be released for Summer '13 (the next release), which will address many issues, including this one.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the changes to the code in the app, and see what happens.

Comment: From Daniel's answer it looks as though no changes can be made to the code: method signatures or bodies!

Comment: Easy on the down-vote! I put in mine first, so I had no way to look into the future to see what he (would) put.

Comment: Did that just get voted today? Does seem like overkill whoever it was!